# Debugger skips a method in a recursive Java program

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a code that prints the maximum steps that have to made in order to jump between cells in double dimensional array when a "step" is allowed only if the int Num given by the user is remainder of the cell next to it.

I have tried to debug but line `return  Q3(A , NUM ,0,  0,0)` skips the command

```
public class Ex14 {
    public static int longestSlope(int[][] A, int num) {

        return recursion(0, 0, A, num);
    }


    private static int recursion(int row, int col, int[][] A, int NUM) {
        if (col < A[0].length)
            return recursion(row, col + 1, A, NUM);
        if (row < A.length)
            recursion(row + 1, col, A, NUM);

        return Q3(A, NUM, 0, 0, 0);
    }


    private static int Q3(int[][] A, int NUM1, int ind1, int ind2, int Step) {

        if ((ind1 + 1) < A.length && A[(ind1 + 1)][(ind2 + 0)] == A[ind1][ind2] - NUM1)
            return Q3(A, NUM1, ind1 + 1, ind2, Step + 1);
        if ((ind1 - 1) > A.length && A[(ind1 - 1)][(ind2 + 0)] == A[ind1][ind2] - NUM1)
            return Q3(A, NUM1, ind1 - 1, ind2, Step + 1);
        if ((ind2 + 1) < A[0].length && A[(ind1 - 0)][(ind2 + 1)] == A[ind1][ind2] - NUM1)
            return Q3(A, NUM1, ind1, ind2 + 1, Step + 1);
        if ((ind2 - 1) > A[0].length && A[(ind1 + 0)][(ind2 - 1)] == A[ind1][ind2] - NUM1)
            return Q3(A, NUM1, ind1, ind2 - 1, Step + 1);
        else return Step; //if a cell next to current index is in the same slop move to that cell and add 1 step

    }
}
```

Here is a tester:

```
public class Tester14 {

    public static void main() {

        /* Tester Question 3 */

        System.out.println("********** Question 3 **********\n");

        int[][] mat = {
            {
                3,
                13,
                15,
                28,
                30
            },
            {
                55,
                54,
                53,
                27,
                26
            },
            {
                54,
                12,
                52,
                51,
                50
            },
            {
                50,
                10,
                8,
                53,
                11
            }
        };

        int num = 1;
        System.out.println("Test1: num => 1");
        System.out.println("Expected result => 6, Student result = " +
            Ex14.longestSlope(mat, num) + "\n");


    }
}
```

Comment: Please note Javascript and Java are 2 totally different programming languages.  I'll remove the tag for you, but for next time don't use the Javascript tag for a Java questions.  Oh, Pointy already removed.. :)

Comment: Take care of Java naming conventions. Method names should start with lower case character

Comment: What do you mean by "skips the command"?  As you step through the debugger, on which line of code do you first observe an unexpected result?  What was the observed result of that line of code?  What was the expected result?  Why?

Comment: from the command " return Q3(A , NUM ,0, 0,0);" I am expecting to get the "Steps" that made in each cell in the array. so for instance on using the tester, on the last cell I am expecting 0 steps because with NUM= 1 there are no cell to go to.

Comment: Make sure you have a breakpoint inside Q3. I know this has already been said but please follow Java naming standards both ours but also your own sake. Code with proper variable and method names is so much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 problems:

- The Q3 recursion only starts from cells in the top row and the
  right-most column. It should start from every cell. So simply loop all cells using 2 for loops instead of using recursion (although that could be done too, of course).
- 2 of the if statements were wrong. See `>= 0` in 2 of the if statements below.

The 2 problems are fixed here:

```
public static int longestSlope(int[][] A, int num) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < A.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < A[0].length; col++) {
            max = Math.max(max, Q3(A, num, row, col, 1));
        }
    }
    return max;
}

private static int Q3(int[][] A, int NUM1, int ind1, int ind2, int Step) {
    if ((ind1 + 1) < A.length && A[(ind1 + 1)][(ind2 + 0)] == A[ind1][ind2] - NUM1)
        return Q3(A, NUM1, ind1 + 1, ind2, Step + 1);
    if ((ind1 - 1) >= 0 && A[(ind1 - 1)][(ind2 + 0)] == A[ind1][ind2] - NUM1)
        return Q3(A, NUM1, ind1 - 1, ind2, Step + 1);
    if ((ind2 + 1) < A[0].length && A[(ind1 - 0)][(ind2 + 1)] == A[ind1][ind2] - NUM1)
        return Q3(A, NUM1, ind1, ind2 + 1, Step + 1);
    if ((ind2 - 1) >= 0 && A[(ind1 + 0)][(ind2 - 1)] == A[ind1][ind2] - NUM1)
        return Q3(A, NUM1, ind1, ind2 - 1, Step + 1);
    else return Step; //if a cell next to current index is in the same slop move to that cell and add 1 step
}
```

Comment: No problems :) Feel free to mark my answer as the Preferred/Correct one (mainly to show people that they no more help is needed here).

Comment: @Stefan I tried your code and i am getting 5 instead of 6.

Comment: int[][] mat = {
                            {3,13,15,28,30},
                            {55,54,53,27,26},
                            {54,12,52,51,50},
                            {50,10,8,53,11}
                        };
                        
        int num = 1;
        System.out.println ("Test1: num => 1");
        System.out.println ("Expected result => 6, Student result = " 
                            + Ex14.longestSlope(mat,num) + "\n");

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your strategy. I'm guessing your code is not doing what you want it to do.

This is what happens in your code: The method recursion will first call itself five times because of the first if statement (col) and then five times because of the second if statement (row). Then it will call Q3 a five times (although I would have guessed 10 times at a first glance). None of the if statements in Q3 evaluate to true to Q3 always returns/fallbacks on 0 (Step).

Please explain what "the int Num given by the user is remainder of the cell next to it". Is it that the difference (cell1-cell2) must be equal to Num. If so, fix your sample matrix since there is no valid path where the difference between the cells is 1 (Num).

Also explain how the step-jumping works. Does it start from and/or end in a specific position? Can it be in any direction (here the answer is probably 'yes')?

Comment: On cell [0,0] none of the ifs return true but on other cell they do, (cell1-cell2) must be equal to Num yes exactly. the function is expected to check all the paths there is on the matrix and return the highest path. I will add a photo of the sample matrix so It will be clearer.

Comment: ok I fount out I can upload a picture but I will try to explain: it's a double dimension array so a "step" is a change of cell either above under left or right to a current cell. for example in the sample matrix a path will be 51,52,53,54,55